# Combining one DF value based on other value in same DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df as below

```
item_no | item_code | item_cost
1001       11111       150
1004       44444       100
1002       22222       120
1001       11112       150
1006       66666       180
1002       22221       160
```

How can i filter the df based on item_no and concat the item_code and add the item_cost and display them in a single row as below:

```
item_no |  item_code   | item_cost
1001      11111,11112       300
1004       44444            100
1002      22222,22221       280
1006       66666            180
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
In [1354]: res = df.astype(str).groupby('item_no', as_index=False).agg({'item_code': ','.join, 'item_cost': lambda x: sum(map(int, x))})

In [1355]: res
Out[1355]: 
  item_no    item_code  item_cost
0    1001  11111,11112        300
1    1002  22222,22221        280
2    1004        44444        100
3    1006        66666        180
```

Comment: How to remove the cost addition part only from the above code ?

Comment: Just remove the item_cost element from the dict.

Comment: If i do that, it is not appending item_code based on item_no

Comment: Can you share the code that you are trying?

Comment: res = df.astype(str).groupby('item_no', as_index=False).agg({'item_code': ','.join})...   because after this line when i try to hardcode the item_cost to a static value, it is throwing error for item_cost

Comment: Can you please open a new question with what you exactly want?